# How to find one unknown number while LCM and GCD is given?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

help me find unknown integer number ***n*** such as

LCM(n,50) = 200

and

GCD(n,50) = 10

how do you solve?

I tried factoring each numbers such as

$200 = 2^3*5^2$

$10 = 2*5$

$50 = 2 * 5^2$

but idk whats next...

edit:

ok thanks for the help I am now able to solve this type of question:) thanks a lot!

[answer on note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDkqk.jpg)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I try factoring each numbers such as 200 is 2^3 x 5^2, 10 is 2 x 5, 50 is 2 x 5^2. but idk whats next

Comment: ok thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{ab}{GCD(a,b)}=LCM(a,b)$

Thus the answer is $n=40$

Comment: thank u i got it!